# Surround Several Words With Quotes At Once In vim

Tags: vim, surround

I was curious if there is a way to surround several words at once with quotes using vim. I am using tpope surround and repeat but I was wondering if there is a command like

```
3ysw"
```

so from

```
one two three
```

to

```
"one" "two" "three"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can visually select the range with `v3e`, and then run a substitution command on it: `:s/\v(\w+)/"\1"/g` (the range `'<,'>` should automatically be inserted).

Personally though, I'd rather surround one word with `ysw"`, and then do `w.w.` (repeat as often as needed).

---

Alternatively, record a macro that does both steps (surrounding and moving on to the next word), then call it n times:

```
qqysw"3wq
```

After this is in your `q` register, you can then call `2@q` to perform the surroundings on the remaining words.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to enquote three words, beginning with the one your cursor is currently placed within, you can do:

```
bv3ec'<Ctrl+r>"'
```

`b` places the cursor at the beginning of the current word, `v` enters visual mode, `3e` jumps at the end of the current 3-word sequence, `c` cuts the selection and enters insert mode, where you insert the left enclosing quote `'` and press `<Ctrl+r>"` in order to paste current contents of the clipboard buffer, before you insert the other enclosing quote `'`.

Omit the leading `b` if you start off with the cursor at the first character of the first word.

Comment: This does exactly what vim-surround does, as opposed to individually quoting every word.

Answer (score 1):

Another substitution option

```
s,\w\+,"&",g

s ............. substitute current line (add %s for the whole file)
\w\+ .......... one word or more
"&" ........... & represents the whole match on the search part
g ............. every occurrence on the line
```

OBS: When using substitution we can use a different delimiter in order to make easy to type. (Also useful when searching for things like "/my/pattern/")